# Connecting a Macbook Pro with an Ipad

Tags: osx, apple

I'm currently using a MacBook Pro Catalina(13-inch, 2020). I was wondering if I could connect it with my Ipad 2. I've tried sidecar, but I believe that the Ipad does not support this feature. Other methods, such as Splashtop Wired XDisplay, haven't ended in success (since the application would not start up on my MacBook). I have the ability to connect my devices using usb, wifi, and bluetooth. I'm not an expert in these things, so if any more information is needed, please ask. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Are you looking for software, or for a howto? In the former case, what do you mean by "connecting" – what features do you need? And what is your price tag?